# How does chrome.browserAction work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to develop my first chrome extension and am running into an issue. Firstly I am using the following boilerplate as a page action:

```
http://extensionizr.com/!#{"modules":["browser-mode","with-persistent-bg","no-bg","with-custom-options","no-override","inject-css","inject-js","jquerymin"],"boolean_perms":["contentSettings","cookies","notifications"],"match_ptrns":[]}
```

In the `inject.js`, it downloads a list of urls from a remote server, checks the current url and if it matches it should do something. I was going to use a notification but I guess the notification comes from the current page and not the extension. So if you start the notification it will say "Do you want to enable notifications for amazon". Then I moved on to changing the icon. I would prefer doing both eventually. However, when I try and set text with the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icons/icon128-x.png'});
```

However, this is what I get in the console.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIcon' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can't access chrome.browserAction in content.js, according to chrome extension document [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

> Additionally, content script can access the following chrome APIs directly:
>
> `i18n
>   storage
>   runtime:
>     connect
>     getManifest
>     getURL
>     id
>     onConnect
>     onMessage
>     sendMessage`
>
> Content scripts are unable to access other APIs directly.

Answer (score 1):

The extension manifest needs a `"browser_action"` section before the chrome.browserAction API is available to it:

> Register your browser action in the extension manifest like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "My extension",
>   ...
>   "browser_action": {
>     "default_icon": {                    // optional
>       "19": "images/icon19.png",         // optional
>       "38": "images/icon38.png"          // optional
>     },
>     "default_title": "Google Mail",      // optional; shown in tooltip
>     "default_popup": "popup.html"        // optional
>   },
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> (From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#manifest.)